# Swapping max and min

Tags: java

So i need to find the max and min in 10 arrays and swap the max and min. If you have Multiple ways to solve this, it would be better.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    int [] integers = new int [10];
    int max = 0;
    int min = 0;
    System.out.println("Please enter the 10 integers:");

    for ( int counter = 0 ; counter < integers.length ; counter++) {
                    integers[counter] = scan.nextInt();
    } // end for loop

    integers[0] = max;
    integers[0] = min;             // keep getting min as 0

    for ( int counter = 0 ; counter < integers.length ; counter++) {
        if ( integers[counter] > max ) {
            max = integers[counter]; 
            maxIndex = counter;
        }
        if ( integers[counter] < min) {
             min = integers[counter] ;
             minIndex = counter;
        }

    }  // end loop

    System.out.println(max);
    System.out.println(min);           

}
```

Comment: Dear Victorious, please don't give us the feeling that we should make your homework. Try to give us information what u already did and what u tried out. Then we could talk about the concrete problems you have

Comment: I think you might mean `min = integers[0];`, rather than `integers[0] = min;`. (Same for max)

Comment: You are absolutely right Mathhias, and thank you alot for remind me and motivating me ( Real Talk) will continue to try till i surrender, also thanks Andy. Worked..  Can you at least give me a hint on swapping? an operator or something, they didnt teach me it thats why

Answer (score 1):

You don't need `max` or `min` (just the indices). Also, you should start at index `1` (the second element) with your comparisons. Finally, after your loop you can swap the values at the two indices. Like,

```
int maxIndex = 0, minIndex = 0;
for (int counter = 1; counter < integers.length; counter++) {
    if (integers[counter] > integers[maxIndex]) {
        maxIndex = counter;
    }
    if (integers[counter] < integers[minIndex]) {
        minIndex = counter;
    }

} // end loop
int t = integers[maxIndex];
integers[maxIndex] = integers[minIndex];
integers[minIndex] = t;
System.out.println(integers[maxIndex]);
System.out.println(integers[minIndex]);
```

Comment: While I believe the code works correctly, I am more in doubt about how much it hepls the original poster. I’d prefer to see an answer that helps fix any issues in the code in the question.

Comment: @OleV.V. I took the code from the question, OP wasn't setting (or using) maxIndex or minIndex. Without those, you can't swap the two elements in the array.

Comment: Thanks alot man, you taught me something, next time i will just ask people to tell me what to do in words " just how you wrote " without the code and i will try till i want to kill myself. Thanks

Comment: would love to see a method that uses the max and min integers. Could i use the ' ^ ' operator by any chance?

Comment: @Fawaz Not to swap the values **in** the array without the indices.

Comment: Well , i need the swap to be in a way such that Input = (1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10) to Output ( 10,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,1) , get me?

Comment: @Fawaz Yes. Which is what I gave you. If you want to do something else, let me know. You can add a `System.out.println(Arrays.toString(integers));` (before and after) to see the effect.

Comment: Well , i need the swap to be in a way such that Input = (1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10) to Output ( 10,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,1) , get me?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a sorting algorithm.Here i used bubble sort.After sorting index 0 element will be min and last index of array will be max and then you can swap them:

```
BufferedReader rd=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));

    try{

        int n=Integer.parseInt(rd.readLine());

        String[] s=rd.readLine().split(" ");

        int[] num=new int[n];

        for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
            num[i]=Integer.parseInt(s[i]);

        }




        int temp=0;
         //bubble sort
        for(int i=0;i<n-1;i++){


            for(int j=0;j<n-1-i;j++){

                if(num[j]>num[j+1]){
                    temp=num[j];
                    num[j]=num[j+1];
                    num[j+1]=temp;
                }
            }
        }

        //swapping max and min
        temp=num[0];
        num[0]=num[n-1];
        num[n-1]=temp;


    }
    catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();

    }
```

Comment: That seems to overcomplicate things.